How can i disable the auto-opening terminal in VS code?
i manage to run a C++ code in my computer terminal thanks to an extension of the marketplace, but when it does, the extension writes a lot of things at the terminal of vs code and then opens the terminal of my computer to run the code, but i just need the external terminal, you know, the terminal of my computer, i'd like to know how to disable the auto opening of the terminal of VS code for everytime it writes something, sorry for my english and for being a princess :/
i've been trying to find a configuration for the terminal of VS code but i don't know which one it could be, i'd like an answer that helps me learn more about VS code and its configuration cuz i'm a newbie, or i'd like to know a new way to run a C++ code at the external terminal using VS code with MinGW

What extension are you using, and how did you configure it?

i use the C/C++ compiler, its the only extension i know that let me run code at external terminal

I hope I understand your question well. Please try these steps and let me know if it worked:
To disable the auto-opening terminal in VS Code, follow these steps:

Open VS Code and click on the "Settings" icon in the bottom left corner of the window.

In the search bar at the top of the Settings window, type "terminal.integrated.shellArgs".

Click on the "Edit in settings.json" button that appears next to the search result.

In the settings.json file, add the following line: "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["-NoStartupWindow"]

Save the file and close it.

Restart VS Code for the changes to take effect.


After following these steps, the terminal should no longer automatically open when you open a new instance of VS Code.

Hi, do you mean that i have to write that on the user settings json?

sorry for late reply. Yes.
